# Полоска между страницами TabBarView(Flutter)

Tags: flutter

когда я перелистываю между страницами есть какая-то белая полоска(между зелеными линиями)(это TabBarView),как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос.

Comment: я приложил фото, вот такая полоска между всеми страницами

Comment: @DenielVarava в релизе на телефоне запустите, должна пройти. Эмуляторы лагают.

Comment: @MiT Спасибо большое!

Comment: @DenielVarava если помог, то поставе галочку рядом с ответом!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в эмуляторе, если запустить на реальном устройстве в режиме `release`, то такие рода проблемы пропадут.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/458997)

Comment: @AlexSazonov вы для начала полностью вопрос и комментарии посмотрите, а потом помечайте ответ "тревогой" с претензией "Сообщения низкого качества
". Можете показать пункт правил по которому мой ответ является "Сообщением низкого качества"?

Comment: не я помещаю сообщения в эту очередь. Вы уже дали ответ в комментарии. Этот ответ является лишним и избыточным. Я рекомендовал к удалению. Дальше модераторы решают. Без всяких претензий к вам.

Comment: @AlexSazonov ответ в комментариях, ничего не значит. Я дал этот ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос, также этим действием я улучшил поиск (так как поисковики только это и индексируют).